# this function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jsfiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/hF3jX/)
this function not working in firefox but 100% working in chrome.what is the reason of that ?

I was create a js code to save elements css for later use.it is working in chrome but not in the firefox why is that ?

```
function css(a){
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for(var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for(var r in rules) {
            if(a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css){
        var s = {};
        if(!css) return s;
        if(css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
            for(var i in css) {
                if((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                    s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
                }
            }
        } else if(typeof css == "string") {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
                var l = css[i].split(": ");
                s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
        }
        return s;
    }

var style = css($("#elementToGetAllCSS"));
$("#elementToPutStyleInto").css(style);
var style = css($("#elementToGetAllCSS1"));
$("#elementToPutStyleInto1").css(style);
```

Comment: What doesn't work at which point? You have HTML errors in your demo, have you removed those?

Comment: Looks identical to me (on W7).

Comment: see the jsfiddel output of throuh firefox and chrome

Comment: Looks related https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449038

Comment: is there any system to fix it?

Comment: not sure why the function doesn't work but the second answer on the question you took the code from seems to be better: http://jsfiddle.net/hF3jX/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict it is in the Firefox now bug has been fixed

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery)

var styles = $("#elementToGetAllCSS").getStyleObject();
$("#elementToPutStyleInto").css(styles);
var styles1 = $("#elementToGetAllCSS1").getStyleObject();
$("#elementToPutStyleInto1").css(styles1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/gwYTE/)